# AutoCompleteTextView dropdown style vs spinner dropdown style

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have `spinner` items showing like this

[image]

On 4.1+ My `AutoCOmpleteTextView` shows the same. However in 5.0+ the `AutoCompleteTextView` shows white dropdown where spinner shows the same Black as above.

How can  i set `AutoCompleteTextView` to show old black,

Something

> spUniversity.setDropDownBackgroundResource()

What resource to put here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was went to android sdk resources and get the standard spinner background and replaced it with popupbackground.

Answer (score 1):

You can style your `AutoCompleteTextView` 
[Check it here.](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/11/styling-autocompletetextview.html)

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Comment: i actually want to use the same theme as above.